# mp4 videos has somehow changed to jpg format

Tags: convert, mp4, jpeg

I was thinking that I have lost some of my `mp4` videos. Now I have found them as a large size `jpg` files. I don't know how that happened bud would like to be able to play them again.

Just renaming them to `mp4` doesn't work... Have someone same experience and know the solution?

Comment: Please add the output of `file filename`, *filename* being any of those mp4/jpg files

Comment: The jpg files are just thumbnails of the mp4 files probably.